# MatHorizontalStepper stepControl with template driven forms

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-stepper

Is there any way to use `[stepControl]` error matcher with template driven forms?  The docs just teach about an AbstractControl instance, which apparently forces the use of a reactiveForm.

I've tried to use `[stepControl]="myNgForm"` and `[linear]="true"` to validate the steps but the stepper just ignores it.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean form input Validation?

Answer (score 16):

The step control seems to work with "form.control".
Here an example with one form per step and template driven forms.

```
  <mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="true">
    <mat-step [stepControl]="form1.control">
       <form #form1="ngForm">
          <input [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" required />
       </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="form2.control">
       <form #form2="ngForm">
          <input [(ngModel)]="address" name="address" required />
       </form>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Angular 10: `Property 'form1' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'`

Comment: Should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 3):

use [stepControl]="myNgForm.controls.[controlGroup]"

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
  <mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="true">
    <mat-step label="Reporting person" ngModelGroup="reportor" [stepControl]="form.controls.reportor">
       <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" ngModel required />
       </mat-form-field>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
</form>
```

Comment: Using `stepControl` and `ngModelGroup` necessarily switch to [Reactive Form programming in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The **ngForm** directive has a property **form** of type **FormGroup**

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Comment: can you provide context around the link in case it ever breaks? thank you!

Comment: This can't be considered as an answer. Elaborate how this info relates to the question and how this info leads to a practical solution to the problem.